# Should I take one scoop of mass gainer or one serving per day?

Tags: supplements

I bought a mass gainer today and I don't understand how to use it, the mass gainer I bought says on it that it is 6 scoops per serving and the scoops are big, per serving it contains 1350 calories, 50g of protein and 17g of fat, should I take one scoop or should I take one serving, one serving of it is a lot in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The point of a mass gainer is to force a calorie surplus.

Mass gainers are typically formulated as a typical dose of protein with a stupidly huge pile of simple carbohydrates mixed in. Your mass gainer probably has 250g of maltodextrin in it. The simple carbs in liquid form reduces the compensatory reduction in consumption you would experience by eating those calories as whole foods. Rather than just consuming the label serving, you need to evaluate the rest of your diet and your goals. If you are trying to gain weight, and you aren’t, then forcing the mass gainer into your diet may help with that. But you need to figure out how much more you need per day to get into a calorie surplus, rather than just slamming an additional 1350 calories just because and accumulating excess fat because of it.